# Ninject MVC 3 and resolving a dependency other than constructor or property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject.web.mvc

I have a solution with a MVC Web Project, Infrastructure project, Services project and Data project.  I installed ninject from NuGet in Visual Studio.  It created a folder in my Web project called "App_Start" and put the Ninject code file in there and my application works completely fine.

My problem is that I have a need to resolve a dependency outside the web project that is a property or in a constructor.

I have tried this in one of my classes in my services project:

```
    var m_customerService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ICustomerService));
```

This returns null every single time.  When I try this exact same thing in my HomeController for example, it returns exactly what I expect.

I suspect that it has something to do with how the projects are referencing each other.  My Web project obviously references all the other projects.  I thought about moving the Ninject start up code to my Infrastructure project so that I will have access to it anywhere.  Does that make sense to do?  Has anybody else had this problem or is there something that I am missing?

Any help on this would awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to explain more about what you mean by "outside the web project".

Comment: I mean by default when I installed the ninject mvc 3 NuGet package it put it in the Website project on my solution.  Would it be possible to move ninject to another project in my solution?  And would that solve the problem of DependencyResolver being null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. I moved Ninject to another project that spans all the projects in my solution and my service classes seem to by working correctly now.